# Property not retaining (ARC)

Tags: objective-c, properties, delegates, automatic-ref-counting, protocols

I have a modal view controller that is presented in the Form sheet style. It has a delegate protocol. I am implementing that protocol and assigning a delegate before presentation but its getting lost even though the property is strong. Any possible causes are welcome. Thanks!

Here is the property declaration, as strong.

```
@protocol SDStoreViewDelegate <NSObject>
// Methods
@end

@interface SDStoreViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id <SDStoreViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

This is where the object is created and the delegate set.

```
SDStoreViewController *store = [[SDStoreViewController alloc] init];
[store setDelegate:self];

NSLog(@"1 %@",store.delegate); // Returns Object as expected

[self presentViewController:store animated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"3 %@",store.delegate); // Returns Object as expected
}];

NSLog(@"4 %@",store.delegate); // Returns Object as expected
```

This is the viewDidLoad of SDStoreViewController. It has already lost it's delegate

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"3 %@",_delegate); //  Returns NULL
}
```

This is the dismiss just because where the delegate would be called it it wasn't NULL.

```
- (void)dismiss:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"5 %@",_delegate); // Returns NULL

    [self.delegate aMethod];
}
```

**Update**

I have used both `weak` and `strong` references. I have also used both `self.delegate` and `_delegate` to access the property. And as a point, the `aMethod` callback is not getting through which is what prompted this detective work to find where it is getting lost.

Comment: Is this the exact code you're using? I could imagine that perhaps you're accidentally presenting a different view controller than the one you're setting the delegate of. Could you log the view controller itself when you present it and in `viewDidLoad` to see if they are the same?

Comment: What @omz is completely true. It's impossible for `-viewDidLoad` to show null and the presentation completion block to show the delegate. `-viewDidLoad` will be called before that completion block is called, so something else is happening (either a masked variable inside your code, or whatever). You need to show the real, exact code you're using.

Comment: This is the exact code. The other things in viewDidload do not effect the delegate. I wouldn't post here if it wasn't a very strange problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's something you're not showing here. As @JasonCoco already said, `viewDidLoad` would be called _before_ the completion block of `presentViewController:...`, which would imply that the delegate is first `nil` but then somehow gets set to the correct value without you doing anything, only to become `nil` again later. Btw, you should use different numbers in your logs, as it is now, you can't distinguish between the two "3" logs.

Comment: It's not possible for this to happen. You either have a different instance of this controller actually being presented, or you have code masking the ivar (which is why we asked you to present all the code). If the object is printed in the completion block correctly and not in `-viewDidLoad`, then you are working with either two different view controller object instances or you have masked your ivar. If it printed nil in the completion block, then we could assume it's getting unset somehow. Print the address of self in `-viewDidLoad` and the address of the controller. Do they differ?

Answer (score 2):

at first, the `delegate` property **must be always** `weak` or `unsafe_unretained` otherwise the `ARC` cannot dealloc the classes with strong pointers to each other.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <SDStoreViewDelegate> delegate;
```

or

```
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) id <SDStoreViewDelegate> delegate;
```

---

why have not you tried to reach the `delegate` property via the getter? like this:

```
NSLog(@"4 %@",self.delegate);
```

instead of

```
NSLog(@"4 %@",_delegate);
```

---

and a bonus question: has your method been called back in that line?

```
[self.delegate aMethod];
```

if the answer is yes, you haven't lost your `delegate`, if the answer is no, where do you set your `delegate` anywhere else?

Comment: It's true that delegates are _usually_ weak references to avoid retain cycles, but it's not always the case. For example, the delegate of `NSURLConnection` is retained, because the connection can decide for itself when to release it (when the connection has finished loading).

Comment: I do normally weak reference delegates but this isn't being set weak or strong. Second I have tried referencing it using self.delegate as normal but tried _delegate just before posting.

Comment: Also the method is NOT being called which is why there is a problem to start with and I began checking the delegate reference using the NSLogs to see where it is getting lost.

Comment: @RyanPoolos, where have you set you `delegate` property anywhere else? because the properties do not lose their pervious content without overriding. can you show us the exact logs with these five lines? the important thing would be the order of the number of log.

Comment: That is the only place the delegate is set. And the NSLog's fire in the order they are numbered appearing in the console in that order.

Comment: @RyanPoolos, so you have two #3 lines on the console; one of them shows the correct pointer, the other one show the `nil`, and after those lines the you see the #4 with the correct pointer again and then the #5 appears with `nil`... am I right? it does not look too consistent... could you copy/paste the correct output with the correct numbers and values from your console and update your question, please?

Answer (score 0):

add a set and get method to the implementation file. right next to the synthesize function.

```
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
- (id)delegate{
    return _delegate; // Add a breakpoint here
}
- (void) setDelegate:(id) delegate {
    if (_delegate != delegate){
        _delegate = delegate; // Add a breakpoint here
    }
}
```

Also put a breakpoint in the `initWithCoder:` method and see if it is getting into there properly.

Comment: This is only needed, if you use Xcode 4.3 or earlier. Since Xcode 4.4 properties are synthesized automatically by the compiler. You also get an ivar with an underscore prefix by default.

Comment: Actually, the `@synthesize` statement was never needed if you provide your own getter and setter as it's done here.

Comment: the getter and setter is only for the breakpoint and to know what is what. the @synthesize method ensures the _delegate property is created. and will take over the methods when you remove them.

Comment: it is nice to have the synthesize automatically done. but there is also something to be said about having the @synthesize method available for you to see, reference, and put comments around. Not that it is definitely required. but I imagine if you put the getter or the setter, the auto generated synthesize may not be available. otherwise how would you customize your properties if they are always auto synthesized.